# Udp punchhole between two instances behind two different cloud NAT on GCP

Tags: nat, cloud, udp, netcat

Hi I'm trying to achieve UDP punchhole concept between two compute instances (on different networks with no public IP) behind two different cloud NATs for their respective networks. It seems that in logging I can see the connection being established but cannot see the message/packet being transferred on the terminal. I dont quite understand what is going on here, can someone help me please? Thanks in advance!

echo "hello" | nc -p 5010 -u <cloudNAT IP 2 > 5009 - vm 2

echo "hello" | nc -p 5009 -u <cloudNAT IP 1> 5010 - vm 1

In both vms i have a screen where i'm listening on port 5009

PSB the screenshot of the logging.

[VM2 connection logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3btXE.png)

[VM1 connection logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aMGF.png)

Comment: Can't you just enter the text of the errors instead using pictures?

Comment: There were no such significant errors, I wasn't able to transfer data from one VM to another as excepted, But in the above 2 screenshots, I was able to see the connection is established. I wasn't using any Wireshark or any other tool so couldn't verify them.

Comment: and why not?Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.